# Coutn unique occurance of match in a line

Tags: regex, perl

I have file with entry:
(----) Manish Garg  74163: V2.0.1_I3_SIT: KeyStroke Logger decrypted file for key stroke displayed a difference of 4 hours from CCM time. - 74163: KeyStroke Logger decrypted file for key stroke displayed a difference of 4 hours from CCM time. 2014/07/04
I want to look  for the unique count of id "74163" or any id in a line.
Currently it gives the output as :
updated_workitem value> "74163"
Count> "2"
But i want the count value as 1.(I dont want to include duplicate entry in count)

```
My code is 
my $workitem;
$file = new IO::File;
$file->open("<compare.log") or die "Cannot open compare.log";
@file_list = <$file>;
$file->close;
foreach $line (@file_list) {

        while ($line =~ m/(\d{4,}[,|:])/g ){
        @temp = split(/[:|,]/, $1);
        push @work_items, $temp[0];
                                        }
                                }

my %count;
my @wi_to_built;
map { $count{$_}++ } @work_items;

foreach $workitem (sort keys (%count)) {
chomp($workitem);
print "updated_workitem value> \"$workitem\"\n";
print "Count> \"$count{$workitem}\"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash to track unique ids found in a particular line:

```
foreach my $line (@file_list) {
    my %line_ids;
    while ($line =~ m/(\d{4,})[,|:]/g ){
        $line_ids{$1} = 1; # Record unique ids
    }
    push @work_items, keys %line_ids; # Save the ids
}
```

Note, I've changed your regex slightly so you don't need to `split` to a temporary array.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicate from array before doing `map { $count{$_}++ } @work_items;`

```
@work_items = uniq(@work_items);

sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep !$seen{$_}++, @_;
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/BtGXQQ)

Comment: Doesn't make sense to remove duplicates then count duplicates.

Comment: I want to get the unique count per line in the file assume same line is repeated 3 times in a file then the count for the id should be displayed as 3.